# Calculating Percentages For "Y" and "N" In Multiple Columns?

Tags: r

I want to be able to calculate percentages for "Y" and "N" in my data frame for multiple columns (e.g., Y and Z), so I tried:

```
Data <- data.frame(
X = sample(1:10),
Y = sample(c("Y", "N"), 10, replace = TRUE),
Z = sample(c("Y", "N"), 10, replace = TRUE), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
table(Data$Y)
prop.table(Data$Y)
```

...but that produces:  Error in sum(x) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument

So, I tried not changing to variable type character and using Factors instead:

```
Data <- data.frame(
X = sample(1:10),
Y = sample(c("Y", "N"), 10, replace = TRUE),
Z = sample(c("Y", "N"), 10, replace = TRUE))
table(Data$Y)
prop.table(Data$Y)
```

...but that produces:  Error in Summary.factor(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), na.rm = FALSE) : ‘sum’ not meaningful for factors

So, I tried transforming it to numeric:

```
transform(Data, Y = as.numeric(Y))
```

...but that produced the previous factor error.

How do you calculate percentages of "Y" and "N" in multiple columns for use in charts, graphs, etc.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do

```
prop.table(table(Data$Y))
###  N   Y 
### 0.4 0.6
```

(with either version of your data.frame)

**EDIT**: If you need to repeat the calculation for each of your columns (assuming they are all binary variables) you can just do:

```
sapply(Data[, -1], function(x) prop.table(table(x)))
###     Y   Z
### N 0.3 0.4
### Y 0.7 0.6
```

(the 'Data[, -1]' is here to remove the first column)

Comment: Thanks. That worked for one column.  Is it possible to calculate multiple columns of "Y" and "N" to percentages, or do you have to type each function separately for each column?